# PHP: minus 2 days excluding weekends and holidays

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm not good at programming, but the task is to calculate another date from a future given date without taking into account weekends and holidays. For example, we set the date `May 3, 2022`, which is **Tuesday**. From this date, I need to subtract 2 days, i.e. `May 1, 2022`, but this is **Sunday**, so we have to return to the first working day before May 1, i.e. `Friday April 29, 2022`.

CMS WordPress. At the moment, my design looks like this:

```
$setDate = get_field('div_registry'); // ACF field, set May 3, 2022
$сutOff = wp_date('j F Y', strtotime('-2 days', strtotime($setDate)));
echo $сutOff; // returns Sunday, May 1, 2022
```

For holidays, as I understand it, an array of dates is needed, but I don't know how to apply it)

Comment: For holidays, you can put a while loop for subtraction until you get a valid day.

Answer (score 0):

For weekends you can do something like this:

```
$setDate = get_field('div_registry'); // ACF field, set May 3, 2022
$сutOff = wp_date('j F Y', strtotime('-2 days', strtotime($setDate)));

if(strpos($cutOff, 'Sunday') !== false) {
   $сutOff = wp_date('j F Y', strtotime('-4 days', strtotime($setDate)));
} else if(strpos($cutOff, 'Saturday') !== false) {
   $сutOff = wp_date('j F Y', strtotime('-3 days', strtotime($setDate)));
}

echo $сutOff;
```